# Language switcher shows me same node on switch

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I am using Locale and Content Translation modules. First I created node and translated it. On content listing both have proper alias urls, everything seems to be ok.

As a guest user I see content in first language when I want to switch to translated version of current node, language switcher block gives me node in the same language (previuosly selected) and url of this node is just raw node url (node/ID). So everything is f up.

Could somebody give me any advice?

More info:

current lang is en:

language switcher links: pl (node/154) and en (en/sample)

en/sample is alias of node/154 :/

But I am sure that I have translated to "pl" node of id 154.

Lanuage codes (admin/config/regional/language):
en, pl

Detections (admin/config/regional/language/configure)
- URL

Comment: Do you have correctly setup the languages codes in the admin interface ? Did you check the language negociation settings ?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Did you try to output the translation links in the node and see if they are OK ? If yes, then something's wrong with the switcher block.

Comment: I just gave up and create one language site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to solve it again and it's was Global Redirect module fault. Please use [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) intead